# readDouble(); java programming

Tags: java

I tried to read the double value using read-double function but its reading as some other value, I gave the input as 15.00 it read as 825568816. please help me to get it correct.

```
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    double d=din.readDouble();
    System.out,println(d);
```

Comment: I'd suggest the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but whats wrong with DataInputStream??

Comment: Look at Jon Skeet's answer below. `DataInputStream` is meant to be used with a `DataOutputStream`. His suggestions for other implementations are easier to use and will give you better results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, don't use `DataInputStream` if you're trying to read *text*. `DataInputStream` is meant for streams of data written by `DataOutputStream` or something similar. Read the documentation for `readDouble` to see exactly what it's doing.

Options for you:

- Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and its [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) method: my experience of questions on Stack Overflow is that `Scanner` is frankly a pain to use correctly
- Create a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader`, and then call `readLine()` to get a line of text, and `Double.parseDouble()` to parse that into a `double`.
- A hybrid approach: use `Scanner`, but only to call `nextLine()` - just a simpler way to read lines of text from `System.in`, basically.

Additionally, you might want to consider using `BigDecimal` - the value "15.00" sounds like it might be a financial value (e.g. a price) - and those should be stored in `BigDecimal` as that can represent *exact* decimal values.